# read-while loop with variables in bash -- equivalent in Python?

Tags: python, bash, while-loop, do-while

Currently refactoring some old code and looking to convert some bash scripts to python.

We have a small piece of functionality written in bash that's similar to:

```
var1=$1
var2=$2
var3=$3

    while read var1 var2 var3; do
       logic
```

To be perfectly honest I'm not sure I understand what this is doing. I've seen while read loops in the context of a file before, but I'm not sure what is happening here with these 3 variables instead of a file.

I'd like to understand what exactly this while read is doing firstly but I haven't been able to find much resources online that explain this logic in the context of variables, all I'm seeing are while read loops that are iterating actual files.

Lastly, I'm looking to convert this functionality into python. Any suggestions for similar Python functionality would be appreciated (still new to python too) but hopefully if I can grasp the logic above first I should be able to find something myself.

Can give more context around the logic in the while loop if required :)

Any help would be grately appreciated

Comment: If the `while` loop's input isn't redirected to a file, it's reading from the terminal. The initial assignments from `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` script reads each line from standard input, splits it into words, and assigns the words to `var1`, `var2, and` var3`in order. It loops until`read` returns an error, which normally happens at EOF.

The roughly equivalent python code would be:

```
while True:
    try:
        var1, var2, var3 = input().split(maxsplit=2)
    except EOFError:
        break
    # logic
```

`maxsplit=2` will make `split()` return at most 3 values. If the input has more than 3 words, all the remaining words will be included in the last word. This is similar to how `read` works when there are more input words than variables.

The Python version won't work if less than 3 words are typed. `bash` will assign an empty string to remaining variables, Python will report an error. There are ways to recode this to solve this problem if necessary.

Comment: `input` doesn't raise `EOFError`; it returns a `''` instead.

Comment: @chepner It returns `''` if you enter a blank line, it raises `EOFError` if you type Ctl-d. That's the same criteria that will stop a `while read` loop.

Comment: Bah, I'm confusing it with `readline` again (which is doubly sad, because I kept trying to think if I *was* confusing it with `readline` before commenting, and clearly came to the wrong conclusion.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and code suggestion, really much appreciated!!

Comment: I was following this post out of pure interest, and just wanted to note that `maxsplit=n` results in a list of `n+1` elements when there are more than `n` words in the source string. So the assignment above for `var1, var2, var3` results in too many values to unpack if the source string contains more than three words. I totally get what the answer is doing though!